# GStreamer text overlay on rtsp restream

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I would like to put a text overlay on a rtsp stream and than restream it with gst-rtsp-server

The restreaming part works but when I want to put the text overlay on it than it fails with can't link erros

my pipe line currently looks like this:

```
./test-launch "(rtspsrc location=rtsp://hostname/video latency=0 ! application/x-rtp, clockrate=90000, encoding-name=H264, profile=high ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96)"
```

when I add a simple textoverlay I get can't link texoverlay0 to rtph264depay, and to the caps or h264parse, or rtph264pay so basicly to nothing.

the pipline with textoverlay looked like this:

```
./test-launch "(rtspsrc location=rtsp://hostname/video latency=0 ! textoverlay text="text" valignment=center halignment=center font-desc=36 ! application/x-rtp, clockrate=90000, encoding-name=H264, profile=high ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96)"
```

How can I add a basic text overlay to the stream?

Comment: Thats not gonna work that way. The first line will just repacketize the RTP data leaving the video bitstream untouched. For what you want to do you will have to decode the video, draw the text on the video and then encode the video again. That means you need a whole transcoding pipeline which is very CPU consuming compared to the first use case.

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I found that I have to decode first, but until now I couldn't make a working pipeline because the stream is very bad, it has embeded data streams which causing all sorts of errors this is why the stream was untouched. On cpu side my server should handle this easily.